# How to set selected value of a dropdownlist in JavaScript. Sharepoint List form

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, drop-down-menu

I want to set Selected value of a Dropdownlist in a Sharepoint List form

I am able to set value using

```
 getField('select','County').selectedIndex = 1;
```

Here it sets the the default selected at index 1

But i want to set the value using Text i.e some `"Abc"`

i tried

```
getField('select','County').selectedValue = "Abc";
getField('select','County').selectedText = "Abc";
```

But both did not work for me. Is there any other property to set the value of a dropDownlist using JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please check this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/BbSLy/5/

you add value in droup down list also select value using javascript with passing text value